# SQL Server Express 2012: cannot select data from table in server instance

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a very strange issue in the server instance of my dev machine:

I have a view called vwAktiveSpieler (active players), having MiID (PK), name, surname, etc. 
it provides members from tbl members joined with a tbl function. I can open this view, it shows me the correct players, all having function=1.

I have a tbl 'Mitgliedsbeitraege' (member fees), with ID (PK), MiID (int) and a description of the fee (nvarchar(Max)).
When I run this query

```
select vwAktiveSpieler.MiID, vwAktiveSpieler.NName + ' ' +[Mannschaft] AS NName
from vwAktiveSpieler
    INNER JOIN Mitgliedsbeitraege ON vwAktiveSpieler.MiID = Mitgliedsbeitraege.MiID
WHERE (Mitgliedsbeitraege.Beitragstext like 'Einschreibgebühr%')
```

I get just 1 record!!
For sure the tbl 'Mitgliedsbeitraege' holds 120 records with this Beitragstext like 'Einschreibgebühr%'.
Because when I avoid using the view and use tbl Members joined with tbl function instead and join this with tbl 'Mitgliedsbeitraege' I get the correct result.

When I run the above query on production machine I get all members who payed this fee!!!
I must say, that on dev machine there is the exact copy of data from the production machine.

It seems, that the view cannot be joined correctly on the dev machine to any reason.
I have absolutely no explanation for that, and I have spent hours and hours to find the problem.

Never before I had this issue with other databases. I use views as "preselections" quiet often. I checked collaction and all settings, but cannot find any difference between dev machine and prod machine instance.

I even deleted the view and created it for new.
Selection another Beitragstext of fee, such as "Training" I get the correct(!) records on both machines.

Any idea?
Thanks
Michael

Comment: for sure SQL server is not wrong - there might be an error in your view or data. ;-)

Comment: did you check all the MiDs of your view (without joining the table Mitgliedsbeitraege)? Then check, if the table Mitgliedsbeitraege includes exactly those MiDs. and furthermore check, if they always should get a match, if the Beitragstext is correct

Comment: is one of the ID columns auto increment? so when copying the data from production zone, they will get new IDs which don't match anymore?

Comment: @mak Are you sure you run under the same login on dev and on prod? Your "tbl function" may filter rows based on login name or smth else, as well as your view can. So please show us your view code and your "tbl function" code

Comment: Could you provide the code of the view please?

Comment: I restored the database from prod machine to dev machine again and query is running as expected! So I suppose that the database was somehow corrupt, otherwise I have no explanation for that. Thanks all for yr efforts. Michael